# How to search nearby private places using google api

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I want to create private places on google map and use nearby service to search those private places.

Google map matrix API - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start

This supports to get distance for given 2 locations.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a software called ARCGIS in order to search private places in google map and its is very useful. Arcgis supports all kinds of versions and reaches almost every subtle places to reach for you. Please see to that you install this software which is going to be very useful and also easy fo you to make the necessary trials and also trails .

Yours Sincerly,
Azhagan